# How to optionally cascade a remove operation in Spring Data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In our object model, using Spring Data, we have some OneToMany relationships. Let's say a Teacher object has many Students:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

As explained here: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete it is possible to use `(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)` behind the annotation, to make sure that every removal of a Teacher removes all of his students.

However, that is not what I want. I usually want the students to remain orphans. So all is fine, I leave the annotation out. Now however, I want to enable the user to choose whether removing a teacher should remove all students. Of course I can loop through the records and do this student by student, but that seems such a waste, because that functionality is already there. So the question is: is it possible to use the built in cascading options on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: it is not possible. And btw simple for (Student s : t.getStudents) em.remove(s) versus switching some internal mechanism on/off depending on user response does not seem as such a "waste" to me, and the straightforward code indicates what is happening.

Comment: True, but cascading mechanisms are of course implemented in the database, which makes them quite different. Also the cascade could propagate through the ranks (for example if student had a list of results), while the manual implementation would remove the students and then the student.remove method would have to do the cascading again. It seems like the margin for error is greater there.

Comment: cascading is implemented on the Java side not DB (unless specially indicated, only using provider extensions not jpa). em.remove(student) will result in the same cascading and sql as if the student was removed due to cascade on teacher deletion.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did not know that the native database constraints were not used.